# ¿Cómo mostrar estos datos con PHP y MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

estoy tratando de hacer una especie de inbox, la parte de las conversaciones, que se vea de esta forma:

[image: especie de inbox que se vea como esto]

Mi tabla en la DB está así:

[image: mi tabla se ve así]

Actualmente tengo este código que está funcionando pero creo no está muy bien hecho:

```
    $query = "

SELECT destino FROM inboxs
WHERE destino='$username' OR de='$username'
UNION
SELECT de FROM inboxs
WHERE destino='$username' OR de='$username'


            ";

    $resultado=$mysqli->query($query);
    while ($rows = $resultado->fetch_assoc())


    {

        if ($rows["destino"] == $username)

        {echo "";}

        else

        {

        echo "


              <table cellspacing=8 cellpadding=7 bgcolor=f5e6fa width=333  onclick='window.location=\"mensajes_2.php?remitente=" .$rows["destino"]. "\"'>
                     <tr>
                        <td valign=top>
                        <font face=Quicksand>
                        <b> " .$rows["destino"]. "</b>
                        </font>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
              </table>

              <table border=0><tr><td height=3></td></tr></table>





              ";

        }
    }


    $resultado->free();
```

Lo que hago es unificar todos los campos, descartar los repetidos, y luego con una condición 
en php, si es igual al usuario de la sesión, lo quita de la lista.

Como comento arriba, me funciona con esto, pero de esta forma cuando trato de mostrar la imagen de perfil que está en otra tabla, no me deja por el 'UNION' por lo que buscaba otra mejor forma de mostrar los datos, tal vez  más sencilla para no tener el problema con la foto de perfil.

Me podrían orientar para poder mostrar los datos de una mejor manera? Gracias de antemano.

Este es un dataset de los registros,

```
INSERT INTO `inboxs` (`id_inbox`, `id_foraneo`, `mensaje1`, `fecha`, `destino`, `de`) VALUES
(306, 1000055, 'Holi', '2020-04-29 21:54:49', 'juliette', 'Ashevega'),
(305, 1000048, 'Hola bonita', '2020-04-29 21:41:04', 'lorena', 'toño'),
(304, 1000048, 'Hola bonita', '2020-04-29 21:40:25', 'cindy_cd', 'toño'),
(303, 1000048, 'Hola bonita, estás bellísima', '2020-04-29 21:28:23', 'juliette', 'toño'),
(302, 1000045, 'Hols', '2020-04-29 21:28:17', 'cindy_cd', 'etrador'),
(301, 1000045, 'Guapa', '2020-04-29 21:26:24', 'lorena', 'etrador'),
(300, 1000045, 'Hola', '2020-04-29 21:26:17', 'lorena', 'etrador');
```

Lo que intento es agrupar tanto por remitente como por destinatario para así poder sacar la lista de conversaciones

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: No me sale error @Bicho, pero de esta forma cuando trato de mostrar la imagen de perfil que está en otra tabla, no me deja por el 'UNION' por lo que buscaba otra mejor forma de mostrar los datos, más sencilla para no tener el problema con la foto de perfil

Comment: Es bastante más complicado obtener el último mensaje de cada conversación para tu inbox, pero veo que sólo obtienes a los interlocutores... ¿Podrías pasarnos un dataset con unos registros de muestra (phpMyAdmin, Exportar) e indicarnos, a partir de esos datos, lo que te gustaría obtener?

Comment: Listo, @DavidJP he actualizado la pregunta con el dataset

Answer (score 0):

Con esta consulta obtendrías la última interacción con cada interlocutor, tal y como aparecen en wsp:

```
SELECT * FROM inboxs WHERE id_inbox IN (
    SELECT MAX(id_inbox) id_inbox FROM (
        SELECT IF(de='toño',destino,de) interlocutor,id_inbox
          FROM inboxs WHERE destino='toño' OR de='toño'  
      ) c1 GROUP BY interlocutor  
  )
  ORDER BY id_inbox DESC;
```

En el caso de `toño` serían:

> ```
> 29/04/2020 21:41:04   lorenaarroyo    Hola bonita
> 29/04/2020 21:40:25   cindy_cd19  Hola bonita
> 29/04/2020 21:28:23   juliette    Hola bonita, estás bellísima
> ```

No sé si es exactamente lo que buscas, pero déjame comentarios a ver si damos con ello.

Sería interesante añadir a tu dataset alguna respuesta de los interlocutores para comprobar que funciona en ambos sentidos

Comment: gracias @DavidJP pero me salieron menos resultados de los que eran, pero tomé tu comentario anterior donde comentabas que era más complicado hacerlo así, e hice una tabla nueva con los interlocutores y funciona bien! gracias! Perdón por contestar hasta ahora, estaba desanimado de que no me saliera :c Saludos!

Comment: Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)